# How to upload document and update properties in one go using C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, file-upload, properties

I am using following code to upload a file in library and setting column values. This library has Major versioning enabled. Problem I am facing is on each file upload, it creates two versions, first version is for file upload and second version is for updating column values.
Can we do it in one go i.e. upload and setting column values only create one version?

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
   {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(mySubSite))
      {
         Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Attachment);
         SPFolder myLibrary = web.Folders[myLibrary];
         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(FileName, bytes, true);
         spfile.ListItemAllFields["Editor"] = web.EnsureUser(UploadedBy).ID;
         spfile.ListItemAllFields["Product"] = Product;
         spfile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
         myLibrary.Update();
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried `spfile.ListItemAllFields.SystemUpdate();` instead of `spfile.ListItemAllFields.Update();` but then it didn't update the `Editor` field and saved it as `System Account`

Comment: Frank, Thanks for accepting my answer, so it should be helpful to you. I saw you are posting the same question in Q&A forum here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/53454/how-to-upload-document-and-update-properties-in-on.html, you could also accept as answer if it solved the question. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is by design.

Using Update() method, Version1 is to create the uploaded file item and Version 2 is to update the metadata column.

Using SystemUpdate() method, it won't update Editor field and generate the new version history, it will set the Editor field with Current Logged User.

A workaround is to open the SPSite with a UserToken which is the same as the value which needs to be set with Editor like this:

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPUserToken token;
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/dev/"))
                {
                    token = site.RootWeb.EnsureUser(@"i:0#.w|contoso\jerry").UserToken;
                }
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/dev/", token))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\passwords.txt");
                        SPFolder myLibrary = web.Folders["DocVersion"];
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add("pwd.txt", bytes, true);
                        spfile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = "TestTitle";
                        spfile.ListItemAllFields.SystemUpdate();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Then it will only generate one version like this:

[image]

This workaround needs to make sure the User in UserToken have enough permission for the site and library.

Reference:

[Update vs. SystemUpdate for SharePoint List Item](http://burnignorance.com/sharepoint-tips-and-hacks/update-vs-systemupdate-for-sharepoint-list-item/)